# How to generate ranges of a column based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

There is a column with numbers- I would like to develop a report that categorizes values of this column into ranges (lower limit and upper limit). This split must happen if the difference in values is more than 10. Is this something achievable by either query in Power BI or SQL Server?

[image: Current column structure]

[image: Required Structure]

Comment: please provide sample data you obtain (your column) and expected result.

Comment: And all in the formatted text rather than the image which can be utilized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, I would use `lag()` and a window `sum()` to define the groups, and then aggregate:

```
select min(x) lower_limit, max(x) upper_limit
from (
    select x, sum(case when x <= lag_x + 10 then 0 else 1 end) over(order by x) grp
    from (select x, lag(x) over(order by x) lag_x from mytable) t
) t
group by grp
```

`lag()` gives you the the previous value. Then, the window sum implements the following logic: everytime the difference between the current and the previous value is more than 10, a new group starts. Finally, the outer query aggregates by group and computes the lower and upper bounds.

Comment: Appreciate your response! It worked like a champ, I just had to make a minor change in the sum code - If the difference is more than 10 then 0 else 1.

Answer (score 3):

GMB's solution is definitely the canonical approach to solving this, by treating it as a variant of gaps-and-islands.  I was wondering if there is a way to do this without two levels of subqueries.  And there is:

```
select coalesce(lag(next_x) over (order by x), first_x) as lower,
       x as upper
from (select t.*,
             first_value(x) over (order by x) as first_x,
             lead(x) over (order by x) as next_x
      from t
     ) t
where next_x is null or next_x > x + 10;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f12b32d4cedfde9e8296089a43f617b) is a db<>fiddle.

It would be interesting to compare the performance on a large set of data -- 2 window functions + aggregation versus 3 window functions + filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, this query also returned result in the format I was expecting.

Comment: That's a clever approach.